# Not able to set variable based on parameters in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to build a new yaml file that reads keyvault secrets based on the parameters at the runtime and declared variables with the condition as per the parameters, but this isn't working.

```
- name: azure_subscription
  displayName: " Select subscription "
  type: string
  default: "service-connection-dev"
  values: 
    - 'service-connection-dev' 
    - 'service-connection-sit'
    - 'service-connection-tes'
    - 'service-connection-prd'

variables:
  
- ${{ if eq('${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}', 'service-connection-sit') }}:
  name: key_vault
  value: 'core-kv-sit'
- ${{ if eq('${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}', 'service-connection-dev') }}:
  name: key_vault
  value: 'core-kv-dev'

stages:
- stage: Validate
  

  ${{ if eq(parameters.azure_subscription, 'service-connection-dev') }}:
    pool:
        name: agent-pool-win-dev
  ${{ if eq(parameters.azure_subscription, 'service-connection-sit')  }}:       
      pool:
        name: agent-pool-win-sit


  jobs:
  - job: Validate
    
    steps:

    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
        KeyVaultName: "${{variables.key_vault}}"
        SecretsFilter: "*"
        RunAsPreJob: false
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}
```

I've tried using variables inside jobs, but that is also not working. Can someone please help?
Also, I'll have to declare 2 more variables as per the parameters input, Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`- ${{ if eq('${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}', 'service-connection-sit') }}:`

You're using a *literal value* of `"${{ parameters.azure_subscription }}"` for the left side of the comparison. The comparison should just be `parameters.azure_subscription`.

So: `- ${{ if eq(parameters.azure_subscription, 'service-connection-sit') }}:`

Comment: this worked. Also I wanted to check if there is a way to declare different variables for a single condition. For example, in this script, I've one condition and pushing a certain value to key-vault based on that condition. Just like this, Is there a way to push values to different variables based on the single condition. 
Ex: if subscription is DEV, then keyvault is key-dev, environment is dev, etc.,